# This is regarding the NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

i tried the below code but my loop is going infinitely.Can someone please helpme with this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nosuchelement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    sum();
    }

    static long  sum() { 
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("The length of the array is:");
        int length=sc.nextInt();
        long a[]=new long[length];
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers of the array");
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            while(sc.hasNextLong())
        {

                 sum +=sc.nextLong();
        }
        }

       return sum;
    }

}
```

what I need is to find the sum of the long type numbers given in the array

Comment: Do you ever enter somthing other than a long? What do you enter? Why do you tell the user to enter the numbers of the array, but never storing anything in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These nested loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    while(sc.hasNextLong()) {
      //..
    }
}
```

Should be

```
for(int i=0;i<length && sc.hasNextLong();i++) {
  // ...
}
```

As you have it currently, you never stop the first iteration of the for loop until the stream is closed; and then all the subsequent iterations of the for loop do nothing, because `hasNextLong()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the while loop used. So just remove `while(sc.hasNextLong())`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nosuchelement
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.out.println(sum());
}

static long sum()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The length of the array is:");
    int length = sc.nextInt();
    long a[] = new long[length];
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers of the array");
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sum += sc.nextLong();
    }

    return sum;
}

}
```